# telephone number format with jquery&regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need to verify and convert any input val into telephone number format, i.e

input **er+f375g25123435s67** i need to convert into **+375 25 1234567**

```
..

keyup: function(){
newval = $(this).val().replace(/(\D+|\+)/g, '');
newval = newval.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$& ');
$(this).val(newval);
}

..
```

this is another code, i need to modify it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strip out non-phone related characters:

```
var phone = "er+f375g25123435s67";
phone = phone.replace(/[^+|\d]/g, "");  // result = "+3752512343567"
```

Then to match phone pattern:

```
if (phone.match(/^[+][0-9]{12}$/)) // or /^[+][0-9]{13}$/ for 13 digits
    ...
```

**EDIT**: Here's what I was able to come up with for the test & replace:

```
phone = $(this).val().replace(/^[^+]{1}/, '');
if (phone.length > 1)
    phone = phone.substring(0,1) + phone.substring(1).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
if (phone.match(/^[+][\d]{12}$/))
    phone = phone.substring(0,4) + " " + phone.substring(4,6) + " " + phone.substring(6,14);
```

Located here: http://jsfiddle.net/cabbott/KaYeJ/

Comment: the first part of code is working, but second one doesn't.. http://jsfiddle.net/jhzy9/

Comment: Your example string has a result of a "+" and 13 digits, while your valid string has 12 digits. I'm not sure which is the correct number of digits.

Comment: dear CAbbott, but i don't need to match phone pattern, i need to transform it on fly (inside the input).. - something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sXGLB/ (the code's almost done)

Comment: I noticed that in your jsfiddle. trying to see if I can come up with a pattern to work with that.

Comment: please press a Fork button and give me a new url

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

// this removes non numeric

> keyup: function(){
>
> var phone = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
>      var myRegexp = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d*)/g
>
> var match = myRegexp.exec(phone);
>      $(this).val('+' + match [1] + ' ' +  match [2] + ' ' + match [3]);
>
> ```
> }
> ```

$1 $2 and $3 should be 375 25 1234567

Comment : sorry didn't know you wanted a full answer with the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/UcJeV/4/

Comment: unfortunately, this code doesn't working (http://jsfiddle.net/cYk4q/) as there's an error here `(\D+|+)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').live({   
    keyup: function() {           
        var ipt = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]*/g, ""); // remove non-digits

        ipt = ipt.replace(/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,7})?.*/g, '+$1 $2 $3');

        $(this).val(ipt);       
    }
});
```

[Fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/sXGLB/6/)

Comment: how to encode  `ipt = "+" + ipt.substring(0, 3) + " " + ipt.substring(4, 6) + " " + ipt.substring(7)` into regular expression?

Comment: I updated my answer with a working one, including a regex to format on the go, check it now please