# telephone number format with jquery&regex done

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [telephone number format with jquery&regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920423/telephone-number-format-with-jqueryregex)

i need to verify and convert any input val into telephone number format, i.e

input **er+f375g25123435s67** i need to convert into **+375 25 1234567**

a most suitable code is:

```
$('input').live({

keyup: function(){

ipt = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]*/g, "");

// remove non-digits

 ipt = "+" + ipt.substring(0, 3) + " " + ipt.substring(4, 6) + " " + ipt.substring(7, 14);

$(this).val(ipt);

}

});
```

but i can't enter numbers after `+375`

1) how to enable numbers after `+375`

2) how to convert `ipt.substring(0, 3) + " " + ipt.substring(4, 6) + " " + ipt.substring(7, 14)` into regular expression?

HERE'S AN ANSWER: http://jsfiddle.net/5UvJr/

Comment: For future reference please update your original question instead of creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You may possibly want to look at this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: yeah, it's rather pretty, but the function of my dream has almoust done.. http://jsfiddle.net/cabbott/KaYeJ/ without jQuery plugins..

Comment: This is a pretty solid plugin, and the basis for the jQuery UI Mask widget still in development: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Mask

Answer (score 0):

The substring indexes are wrong, try this:

```
ipt = "+" + ipt.substring(0, 3) + " " + ipt.substring(3, 5) + " " + ipt.substring(5, 12);
```

Comment: thanks, i have an answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/kXnBn/

Comment: of course, i had been waiting for 8 hours - this is a limit until my rating is under 100 ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/5UvJr/

```
$('input').live({

  keyup: function(){

  var phone = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

  phone = phone.substring(0,12);

  var myRegexp = /(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d*)/g
  var mphone = myRegexp.exec(phone);    

  $(this).val('+' + mphone [1] + ' ' +  mphone [2] + ' ' + mphone [3]);
 }
});
```